# SSRS access custom code from all reports

Tags: reporting-services

I've embedded custom code in a report to check for division by zeros. 
Is it possible to access this Code in my other reports without having to embed the same code in all reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sharing code between reports your best option is to deploy a custom assembly to the Report Server and reference this in your reports:

[Using Custom Assemblies](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920769).